# React: Passing callback functions as props

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a custom modal functionality where i need to close the modal after data submission is successful. I am able to pass simple function as props but if i try to pass with a callback, it returns an error. The error returned here:
ParentComponent.js: Uncaught TypeError: cb is not a function

My code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';


function CustomModal({btnVariant, btnClass, btnTxt, modalTitle, children, handleSave}) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

    const localHandleSave = (e) => {
        handleSave(e, (err) => {
            console.log('i am called back');
            //handleClose() //here i will close it after the submission was successful
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Button variant={btnVariant} className={btnClass} onClick={handleShow}>
                {btnTxt}
            </Button>

            <Modal show={show} backdrop="static" keyboard={false} size="lg" onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{modalTitle}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {children}
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                    Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={(event) => localHandleSave(event)}>
                    Save
                </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>  
        </>
    );
}

export default CustomModal;
```

Parent component

```
import CustomModal from './../../components/customModal/CustomModal';

import styles from './parentComponent.module.css';

function ParentComponent() {
    const onSubmit = (e, cb) => {
        //after api request is successfull...
        cb(null);
    };

    return (
        <div>
          <CustomModal btnVariant="info" btnClass={styles.pull__right} btnTxt="+ Add" modalTitle="Add data" handleSave={onSubmit} />
        </div>
    ); }

export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "close the modal" after API request success? not to show it? make it invisible?

Comment: have you checked  `cb` comes from CustomModal is not undefined ? 
could you do console(cb) in your ParentComponent with guard nullish if(cb){cb(null)}

Comment: I think it should be work well without an error

Comment: @EricCheng yes. It should be invisible

Comment: @dante the callback will be in parentComponent's onSubmit function. The ModalComponent has to wait for the api request to be successful and then hide the modal

Comment: For make sure variable already pass the `handleSave` do console.log(e) inside `onSubmit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your comment reply what you want to do is to make the child invisible, then you don't need a callback, just define a state variable, and switch to not showing the child component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CustomModal from './../../components/customModal/CustomModal';
import styles from './parentComponent.module.css';

function ParentComponent() {
    const [isShowCM, setIsShowCM] = useStatus(true);
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        //after api request is successfull...
        setIsShowCM(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
          {isShowCM ? (
          <CustomModal btnVariant="info" btnClass={styles.pull__right} btnTxt="+ Add" modalTitle="Add data" handleSave={onSubmit} />
          ) : null}
        </div>
    ); }

export default ParentComponent;
```